# change a div background based on variable passed to jsp

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I have Java object get passed via servlet, for each element in that has map I generate a div.
Example:

```
    <c:forEach items="${myObject}" var="aRec" varStatus="mapLoop">
        <div class="row borderRecords">
```

I want to change the background color of the div based on a value in that object example: `myObject.isSuccess` I want to color the div. What is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess JSTL tags has several options to use.

```
<c:if test="${aRec > 'some value'}">
    <div class="row borderRecords">
</c:if>
```

You can find a lot of posts about c:if, else syntax.

However, I prefer to use jQuery instead of JSTL.

Answer (score 1):

many ways to skin a cat

1) Have the Java object hold the css class name and then have the style sheet define the style

```
<div class="${myObject.styleClass} row borderRecords"
```

2) Have logic in you jsp file

```
 <c:if test="${myObject.isSuccess}"><div class="someOther row borderRecords">
```

3) Use jquery to process after document has loaded.